# Нелогичное поведение call_user_func_array

Tags: php

Почему вот этот код:

`var_dump(call_user_func_array('in_array', [1 => [1,2,3], 0 => 2]));`

ругается "Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, integer given" ?

Там же передается массив в call_user_func_array. Разве она не должна сопоставлять и индексы тоже? Я специально поменял местами аргументы, но поставил правильные индексы чтобы это проверить.

P.S. Обнаружил это когда пытался реализовать каррирование. Взял пример из [этой](https://habrahabr.ru/post/144160/) статьи. Вот пример из реального кода что я хотел сделать (данные только другие):

```
$a = [1, 2, 3];
$b = [4, 1, 5, 3];
// код функции curry есть в статье
var_dump(array_filter($b, curry('in_array', [1 => $a])));
```

Это короче чем писать анонимную функцию (ох как же мне не хватает стрелочных лямбд...). Но ведь не работает. :( А все потому что call_user_func_array не хочет сопоставлять индексы.

Comment: @Jean-Claude нет, в этом весь смысл. Мне надо чтобы так работало за счет индексов. Иначе не получится каррировать.

Comment: @Jean-Claude спс, Капитан Очевидность. Я об этом и говорю - поведение нелогичное. Раз она принимает массив - она должна смотреть и на индексы по идее.

Comment: ладно, потер прошлое. Зато работает call_user_func_array('in_array', ['baba' => 2,'deda' => [1,2,3]]), что как бы тоже неплохая возможность для разработчика.

Comment: Если посмотреть исходники, то становится ясно. Функция [call_user_func_array](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/2002597/) вызывает внутри себя функцию [array array_values ( array $array )](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-values.php). А `array_values()` возвращает массив со всеми элементами массива array и **она также заново индексирует возвращаемый массив числовыми индексами**. Видимо это сделано для динамического определения из контекста при вызове. Вы кстати можете взять исходник функция и сделать свою `call_user_func_array`, что бы сортировка сохранилась))

Comment: это вы типа `array_intersect` пытались реализовать с помощью `array_filter` и `in_array` ?

Comment: @teran ни разу нет. Я же четко написал что я пытался сделать каррирование.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Немного переделал реализацию каррирующей функции из статьи и заработало.

```
function curry($callback, $args = []) {
    $num = (new ReflectionFunction($callback))->getNumberOfRequiredParameters();

    return function() use($callback, $args, $num) {
        $args += func_get_args();
        ksort($args);
        return count($args) < $num ? curry($callback, $args) : call_user_func_array($callback, $args);
    };
}
```

Оказывается array_merge (который был в оригинале) не сохраняет ключи. А через простое сложение массивов все сохраняется. :D Плюс еще сортировку по ключам добавил, раз уж оно само не умеет.